# Drupal 7 multisites with subsite sharing main site data

Tags: 7, multi-sites

I have created a multi-site  Drupal 7 in my localhost environment  with a main-site and a sub-site in it with a single database, with table names of sub-site prefixed with 'sub_'. If I tried editing the setting.php of sub-site, altering 'prefix' value in database array  to a shared table I cant access the sub-site own table. I need the sub-site to access both shared table and its own table. 
So that if any content/content-type created in main-site has to be reflected in sub-site.But the content/content-type created in sub-site should not be reflected in main-site.

How to achieve it?

Comment: Hi @Sidhess. :) After the question was closed, you've edited it. This means I find it in the "re-open queue". However, you've given no comment as to why your question is no a duplicate as has previously been determined. I almost rejected the re-open because of this, but reading the question edit closer I see your question is now different. I'm voting to re-open but please update your title, as it doesn't properly reflect your question any more.

Comment: @Molot,Clive..When I have tried altering the prefix value in settings.php the main site & sub site shares same table and so sub-site cant access its own table.. so I was forced to put every records of sub-site's table to shared table. So now records of sub-site become obviously visible in main-site too. But I need a little privacy to sub-site so that the records wont be visible to main-site but the sub-site need to access the main site data.